# Trying to loop through a list that contains multiple items inside it

Tags: python, loops, gps, folium

#### Problem

I'm mapping coordinates to a map using folium, my coordinates are stored in a list such as this e.g:

> [[51.52765, -0.1322611111111111], [53.54326944444444, -2.633125]].

Now when I tell folium to map a coordinate from the list, I have to specify it like this:

```
folium.Marker(all_coords[1]).add_to(m) #[1] = the first set of coordinates from my list.
```

My list contains a lot of coordinates and in order to print them all out I have to do this:

```
folium.Marker(all_coords[1]).add_to(m) #[1] = the first set of coordinates from my list.
folium.Marker(all_coords[2]).add_to(m) #[2] = the second set of coordinates from my list.
folium.Marker(all_coords[3]).add_to(m) #[3] = the third set of coordinates from my list.
folium.Marker(all_coords[4]).add_to(m) #[4] = the fourth set of coordinates from my list.
folium.Marker(all_coords[5]).add_to(m) #[5] = the fifth set of coordinates from my list.
```

How would I go about telling folium to read all items from my list one by one?

*Any help is appreciated thank you :)*

Comment: `for coord in all_coords: folium.Marker(coord).add_to(m)`?

Comment: @matt Could you post that as an answer and close the question?

Comment: The suggested duplicate doesn't have an accepted answer and the top-voted answer links to a notebook for code samples. I suggest posting and accepting an answer here instead.

Comment: @dspencer it's literally just a `for` loop, though :/ The OP merely needed to implement what they said in the title

Answer (score 1):

Yes , [@roganjosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799172/roganjosh) is absolutely right. What you are trying to achieve can be done using the python `for` loop or `while` loop.

Of those the for loop is the best since looping variable is automatically defined.
Therefore instead of indexes, you can iterate through the list by:

```
 for i in all_coords:
    folium.Marker(i).add_to(m)
```

This is also clearly shown [here](https://python-graph-gallery.com/312-add-markers-on-folium-map/).